# Manually setting the size of a node and forcing contents to 'fill' node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an expression "a = function(b)" inside a node. But "a =" and "function(b)" appear on separate lines. I can force the node to be wider, but this doesn't change how the writing inside is laid out. How can I fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: Please see below:

```
\documentclass[12pt article]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\node [block] (A) {Some writing, a = function(b)};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a short example of the code that's causing you trouble.

Comment: Did you use the `text width` option by any chance? Nevermind, I see that you do. It is simply due to the fact that your defined width is too narrow for it.

Comment: The width of the text block is defined by `text width`, so even if you increase the size of the node, that won't change the text. Can't you set `text width` to a larger value, e.g. 8em? Another option is perhaps to not set the text width, and define the line breaks manually, with `\\\`. (Edit: Too late ...)

Comment: as already said it is the `text width` setting. so forcing it will result in a bad box warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in math mode, you solve it by adding curly braces, such as

```
${a = function(b)}$
```

If it's in text mode, though I would use math mode, you could use `\mbox`:

```
\mbox{a = function(b)}
```

Both prevent the line break, also in TikZ nodes.

Comment: But I think there shouldn't be any reason for tikz to break the line if there is enough space (Matt said "I can force the node to be wider"). I think there might be some problem with his code...